# how to constrain second day that it has always been bigger than first in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

How to constrain second day that it has always been bigger than first?

```
<%
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String today = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    String tomorrow = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
%>
<p><input type="date" name="from" min="<%=today%>" value="<%=today%>"/></p>
<p><input type="date" name="to" min="<%=tomorrow%>" value="<%=tomorrow%>"/></p>
```

Comment: You want to check tomorrow is greater than today?

Comment: I want to set minimum tomorrow is greater than the already entered today

Comment: You can http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date- to check the date entered.

Comment: What is "minimum tomorrow"? Your question makes no sense as currently written. Please edit carefully to explain your intent. Are you taking about the time-of-day?